# how to display georeferenced image in matlab GUI?

Tags: matlab-guide, coordinate-systems, satellite-image

i have a gui that its goal is to show a multispectral satellite image. i import the image as follow:

```
    [img, R] = geotiffread('myimage.tif');
```

thus i have the coordinate of 4 corner(R). i wonder how could i display this coordinate in my gui and also get the value of coordinate when i click on the image? the command that i use is:

```
imshow(img);
```

should i use another command like mapshow? my final gui should be something like

```
mapview
```

that show the coordinate and scale of the image below it. i am able to show the Frame coordinate in a static text box but i have problem about the real coordinate.

many many thanks

Comment: Ok however after a month nobody asnwer me!! but i found the answer. it is really simple. pix2map is a matlab function that converts the pixel coordinate to map coordinate! that all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok unfortunately after a month nobody answered me but I found the answer.

It was really simple. `pix2map` is a function from Matlab's "Mapping Toolbox" that converts the pixel coordinate to map coordinate.

That was all it took.